# How to solve reference error response data is not defined in MEAN stack api project?

Tags: node.js, express

I’m trying to build an API with mean stack, but when I test the endpoint with a get request using postman, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: studentData is not defined
at module.exports.StudentsGetAll (F:\MEAN\api\controllers\students.controllers.js:13:11)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (F:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

However if send a second get request the studentData response is returned as I want it. What am I doing wrong?

**Students.controllers.js**

```
var dbconn = require('../data/dbconnection.js');


module.exports.StudentsGetAll = function( req, res) {

dbconn.open();
console.log('GET the Students');

res
.status(200)
.json(studentData);
};
```

**Dbconnection.js**

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var query = require('./queries.js');
var dburl = 'mssql://*****:****@**.**.*.**/******/*******';

function open() {
  var conn = new sql.Connection(dburl);
  var req = new sql.Request(conn);

  conn.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Database Connection established");
      req.query(query.getAllQuery, function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          studentData = recordset;
        }
      });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  open : open
};
```

How can define the response data before it actually exists? I am confused can anyone explain where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the first try, your code will respond before the database connection was established. The second time would work better because the db connection was established already after the first try.

A database connection will block the I/O. Meaning that you should implement a callback function to be performed after the connection is made and then respond with the data retrieved.

I would re-write the Students.controllers to the following:

```
// Students.controllers.js

var dbconn = require('../data/dbconnection.js');


module.exports.StudentsGetAll = function( req, res) {

   var getStudentData = function(studentData){
        res
        .status(200)
        .json(studentData);
        };

    dbconn.open(getStudentData);
    console.log('Getting Students Records');
}

//Dbconnection.js

var sql = require('mssql');
var query = require('./queries.js');
var dburl = 'mssql://*****:****@**.**.*.**/******/*******';

function open(callback) {
  var conn = new sql.Connection(dburl);
  var req = new sql.Request(conn);

  conn.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback({error: err}); // Respond back with error
        return;
      }
      console.log("Database Connection established");
      req.query(query.getAllQuery, function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          callback({error: err}); // Respond back with error
        }
        else {
          // Added Callback
          callback(recordset); // Respond back with data set
        }
      });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  open : open
};
```

Comment: thankyou for that, I have tried it and I think I understand what you mean though I am getting another error: F:\MEAN\api\controllers\students.controllers.js:17
dbconn.open(getStudentData);   I dont seem to be able to remove it any thoughts?

Comment: Thankyou Peter I appreciate your help

Comment: good news is i got rid of the error by removing the closing curly brace as there was one too many however bad news is it is still not working, dbconn object is empty for some reason?

Comment: ok i saw that i updated to fixed that curly brace..What error are you getting now?

Comment: Hi @Peter Hauge, yes the dbconn object is empty for some reason it's not getting anything from dbconnection.js could it be something to do with the node module MSSQL that im using ? the code I was using was straight from their readme doc.

Comment: Thanks very much Peter I hadn't seen your edit, it works perfectly now, I had only removed one curly brace when i checked again I saw that you removed two, great answer and I really appreciate your help :)